# Constructing function from a closure with Magrittr is resulting in an error upon function evaluation

Tags: r, closures, magrittr

When I use magrittr to pass a value for x to the function below, it results in an unusable function. Why is this happening? I have version magrittr_1.5.

```
library(magrittr)
f <- function(x) { function(y) { x + y } }

# Case 1 (works)
f.5 <- f(5)
f.5(6) # returns 11

# Case 2 (works)
f.5 <- f(5) 
6 %>% f.5 # returns 11

# Case 3 (fails)
f.5 <- 5 %>% f
6 %>% f.5 # Error in x + y (from 1) : 
          # non-numeric argument to binary operator 

# Case 4 (fails)
f.5 <- 5 %>% f
f.5(6); # Same error as case 3
```

Comment: The technical notes on the `%>%` help may be useful: *The magrittr pipe operators use non-standard evaluation. They capture their inputs and examines them to figure out how to proceed. First a function is produced from all of the individual right-hand side expressions, and then the result is obtained by applying this function to the left-hand side. For most purposes, one can disregard the subtle aspects of magrittr's evaluation, but some functions may capture their calling environment, and thus using the operators will not be exactly equivalent to the "standard call" without pipe-operators.*

Comment: Though I never use magrittr to produce functions (my use of `%>%` is limited only to `dplyr, rvest` and few other vis packages), I think, `pipeR` has a better design for pipelined operations. Case3 in your example works perfectly fine with pipeR's `%>>%`.

Comment: `5 %>>% f %>>% {.(6)}`

Comment: This actually seems strange enough to warrent an issue @ github.com/smbache/magrittr/issues

Comment: @Stefan I've made an issue at that link, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial answer.  First off, it is easy to make it work if you evaluate `x` in the calling environment of the inner anonymous function,

```
library(magrittr)
f <- function(x) { x; function(y) x + y }
f.5 <- 5 %>% f
6 %>% f.5
# [1] 11
```

To investigate what is going wrong, see what `x` is evaluating to,

```
f <- function(x) {
    function(y) {
        print(sprintf("x: %s.", toString(x)))
        x + y
    }
}
## the failing case
fails <- 5 %>% f
6 %>% fails
# [1] "x: function (y) \n{\n    print(sprintf(\"x: %s\", toString(x)))\n    x + y\n}, TRUE"
```

It is pointing the result of calling `withVisible` on `f`, which happens when a function, `freduce`, is called ([code](https://github.com/smbache/magrittr/blob/master/R/freduce.R)).  In the body of the `pipe` function, there is a line,

```
body(magrittr:::pipe)[[2]][[3]][[10]]
# env[["freduce"]] <- freduce
```

where `freduce` is made available (look at `magrittr:::pipe` for full context).

If this line is modified to simply be the actual code in the function `freduce` (ie. copying `magrittr:::freduce`), it seems to work,

```
## Make a modified %>% operator
mypipe <- magrittr:::pipe

## Change that line
body(mypipe)[[2]][[3]][[10]] <- quote(
    env[["freduce"]] <-
        function(value, function_list) {
            k <- length(function_list)
            if (k == 1L) {
                result <- withVisible(function_list[[1L]](value))
                if (result[["visible"]])
                    result[["value"]]
                else
                    invisible(result[["value"]])
            } else {
                Recall(function_list[[1L]](value), function_list[-1L])
            }
        }
)

## Redefine
`%>%` <- mypipe()

## Test (now it works?!)
fails <- 5 %>% f
6 %>% fails
# [1] "x: 5"
# [1] 11
```

So, this is a partial solution because I can't figure out why redefining `freduce` in this way makes it work.